# Get child value based on timestamp for each parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have these 2 tables in SQL Server 2012
[image: parent-child_tables]

For each parent I would like to retrieve value based on the most recent timestamp.

This is what I've got so far by doing some searching and trial and error.

```
select m.id, m.Name, mmi.previousValue
from [ManualMeters] m
inner join 
(
    select mm.ManualMeterId, max(mm.Value) previousValue
    from ManualMetersInput mm 
    --where mm.Timestamp = max(mm.Timestamp)
    group by mm.ManualMeterId
        having count(*) > 1
) mmi on (mmi.ManualMeterId = m.Id )
```

So I would expect here to see:

```
ID    Name       previousValue   TimeStamp
1     Meter_1    5000            2016-03-19 12:00
2     Meter_2    3500            2016-03-18 12:15
```

Now it only shows max values but that isn't what I need. I need the value from the most recent timestamp.

Comment: This question is a good question: You state your RDBMS *with version*, you provide sample data, you show your own effort and you state the expected output. Worth an upvote. **BUT**: Please **do not** post your data as an image! Make it copy'n'pasteable, best with dedicated `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this :

```
SELECT   m.id, m.Name, mmi.previousValue, mmi.TimeStamp
FROM    [ManualMeters] m
LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT   ManualMeterId, Value AS previousValue, TimeStamp, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (PARTITION BY ManualMeterId  ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM    ManualMetersInput

        ) mmi ON mmi.ManualMeterId = m.Id  And RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Would have never found this myself. :)

Comment: Thats one way to do it, other answers proposed by my fellows are good too. Picking up the right one depends mostly on your number of records.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is LAST_VALUE windowing function:

```
    select m.id, m.Name, mmi.previousValue
    from [ManualMeters] m
    inner join 
    (
        select DISTINCT
          mm.ManualMeterId, 
          LAST_VALUE(mm.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY mm.ManualMeterId ORDER BY  mm.Timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) previousValue,
          LAST_VALUE(mm.Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY mm.ManualMeterId ORDER BY  mm.Timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) previousTimestamp
        from ManualMetersInput mm 

    ) mmi on (mmi.ManualMeterId = m.Id )
```

More explanation on [LAST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) and [OVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clauses.

Comment: Gives error: Column 'ManualMetersInput.Timestamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Works now, but the timestamp is missing in the results..
What method is the fastest if you would have lots of records?

Comment: You can use LAST_VALUE with exactly the same partition, order and range but ask for timestamp